# How to display x and y axis values of where the crosshair line intersects in series using Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have been working on a project that uses highchart to draw multiple line charts.  With that, I have already achieved some configuration (eg. x-axis crosshair, fixed tooltip, zooming) for my chart in accordance to the business requirements.  As such, one requirement is that when x-axis crosshair moves from left to right  (or vice versa) within the plotted chart, the selected values on y-axis and dates and time on x-axis will be displayed in the fixed tooltip.

**Example:** 
Series CDT158 has a value of 100.46 (as shown in Chart 1) on 27 Apr 2017 20:49:48 pm.  When I move the x-axis crosshair to the right, it jumps directly to the next point which has a value of 103.47 (as shown in Chart 2) on 27 Apr 2017 20:50:38 pm.

Is it possible when the crosshair passes through the series (from one point to the next point), the y-axis values between 100.46 and 103.47 as well the datetime values on x-axis will be rendered in the fixed tooltip? I also want to display the CDEP158 y-axis values simultaneously in the fixed tooltip.  How can I achieve this?

[**Chart 1**]

[image: Chart1]

[**Chart 2**]

[image: Chart2]

This is the Highchart initialization.

```
myChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'line',
        zoomType: 'xy',
        panning: true,
        panKey: 'shift',
        plotBorderWidth: 1
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'horizontal',
        align: 'left',
        itemDistance: 10,
        borderWidth: 0,
        itemMarginTop: 0,
        itemMarginBottom: 0,
        padding: 20
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                format: '{y}'
            },
            allowPointSelect: false
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            rotation: -65,
            style: {
                fontSize: '9px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        },
        crosshair: true,
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
          second: '%d %b %Y <br/> %H:%M:%S %P',
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
        gridLineColor: '#DDDDDD',
        gridLineWidth: 0.5
    },
    tooltip: {
        positioner: function () {
            return {
                x: this.chart.plotLeft,
                y: this.chart.plotTop
            }
        },
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function (tooltip) {
            var formattedDate = Highcharts.dateFormat('%d %b %Y <br/> %H:%M:%S %P', new Date(this.x));
            const header = `<span style="font-size: 8px">${formattedDate}</span><br/>`;
            let body = this.points.reduce((body, p) => body + `<small><font color="${p.series.color}"><strong>${p.series.name}</strong></font>: <strong>${p.y}</strong></small><br/>`, '');
            return header + body;
        },
        shared: true,
        valueDecimals: 2,
        //followPointer: true,
        shadow: false,
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)'
    },
    series: [{
            name: 'CDT158',
        data: [
            [1493326164493, 87.54],
            [1493326174018, 97.09],
            [1493326188245, 100.46],
            [1493326238635, 103.47],
            [1493326284930, 106.12]
          ]
    },{
            name: 'CDEP158',
        data: [
                [1493326165993, 94.34],
            [1493326174772, 88.87],
            [1493326188895, 98.25],
            [1493326272411, 96.48],
            [1493326299520, 100.13]
        ]
    }]
});
```

I'm pretty sure that this can be achieved through Highcharts but, my limited knowledge and experience in Highchart stops me to figure it out.

I have posted a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5r9xrqLa/29/) that illustrate the above scenario.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you try to achieve? Do you want to disable snaping for a tooltip - so bascially you want to update the tooltip values on every mousemove? And those values are interpolation between two points?

Comment: @morganfree, thanks for your response.  Basically, yes.  I need the x and y values where the vertical line intersects the series (not where the mouse pointer is).  You are right, the exact word is "interpolation" between two points (x & y).  Is that possible for a multiple series?

Comment: @morganfree I found this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/uj0dnwmt/) via an old post in GitHub highcharts repo w/c is similar to what I'm trying to achieve. Instead of displaying y-axis values `yAxis.crosshair.label`; I want to display this in a fixed tooltip.  I have [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uj0dnwmt/10/) to show the fixed tooltip with y-axis values in it.  But, it doesn't get/display the y-axis values in the tooltip of where the crosshair line intersects on a series? I tried to read the code but sadly my Javascript knowledge doesn't reach to such levels.  Please help me?

Comment: In the example you have x values are numbers not timestamps - http://jsfiddle.net/uj0dnwmt/11/ You are transforming x to be 00000000000001 If you use timestamp and x your date will be changing http://jsfiddle.net/uj0dnwmt/12/

Comment: @morganfree, thanks for your response.  yeah, I noticed that.  However, as of this writing, Highcharts does not directly support this kind of scenario.  Because, only one horizontal crosshair is supported (for the closest point to the mouse position).  I'm hoping that they will add this in the next future release.